# Format with array of variants?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, variant

How can I use `Format` with an array of `Variant`? I have an exception that should store the message and the parameters separately so that translation can be done at the top-level:

```
TMyException = class (Exception)
private
  FParams : array of Variant;
public
  constructor Create (const Msg : String);
  constructor CreateFmt (const Msg : String; Args : array of Variant);
end;
```

Now how can I later use `Format` with the stored values?

Comment: you need TVarRec rather than variant: http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html

Comment: @David: thanks again! Make this an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Array of const, as used by Format and similar, is actually implemented as an open array of [TVarRec](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/en/System.TVarRec). Whilst superficially similar to variant, TVarRec is a different beast. I recommend Rudy Velthuis's excellent [article](http://rvelthuis.de/articles/articles-openarr.html) explaining some of the detail needed in order to copy and manipulate arrays of TVarRec.